# When swapping two axes in higher dimensional coordinate system, what happens to all the other axes?

Tags: intuition, coordinate-systems, rotations

In the 3D Euclidean coordinate system, say I want to swap the positions of the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis while retaining the right-handedness of the system.

Such a swapping of $x$ and $y$ is equivalent to first rotation the coordinate system by $\pi$ around either $x$ or $y$ and then rotating it $-\pi/2$ around $z.$ The result is that $x$ and $y$ have switched places and $z$ has been inverted.

My question is how this generalizes to higher dimensions: If I have a coordinate system in $n$ dimensions and I swap two axes $x$ and $y$, what happens to the rest of the axes? Are they all inverted? E.g., if $w$ is one of the other axes, does the mapping $\mathrm{swap}(x,y)$ result in $w\rightarrow -w$?

Thanks.

Comment: Swapping two axes and keeping the orientation results in the reversing of any _odd number_ of other axes. You can freely choose which axes, and how many, as long as you keep to this restriction.

Comment: @Arthur Huh, I didn't expect that! How did you see this? Thanks.

Comment: The intuitive reasoning is that you can restrict your $n$-dim space to the $3$-dim space spanned by the two axes you want to swap, together with any third axis of your choice. Then do to these three what you did to $\Bbb R^3$ above. This doesn't change the orientation, nor any of the other axes. As for if you want to reflect more axes, you can take any two axes, restrict to the plane spanned by those two and rotate the two axes $180^\circ$ within that plane, which turns both the axes around without changing any of the other axes, and without changing the orientation.

Comment: You can also look at it in terms of matrix determinants. The matrix of an axis swap will be the identity matrix with the columns that correspond to the two axes exchanged. Exchanging columns multiples a determinant by $-1$, and a negative determinant indicates a change in chirality. To get back to a determinant of $1$, you have to multiply an odd number of columns by $-1$, which reverses the corresponding axes.

Comment: @amd That is a very neat way of seeing what Arthur said is true - I'd happily accept that as an answer, if you were to also explain why the change of sign of the determinant corresponds to a change of chirality.

Comment: That question goes to the heart of what we mean by orientation. I’ll try to come up with something succinct tonight.

Comment: I think exactly as amd. After swapping we had **odd** number of columns to multiply by $-1$ to return to determinant equal $1$. So in $n>3$ dimension it can be made by many ways, e.g. in $4$ dimension by 2 ways.

Comment: However for $n=4$ after swapping two initial columns, two remaining ones could also be swapped and this operation  would also preserve determinant to be equal 1,so multiply by -1 is not the only choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a brief (I hope) digression regarding orientation. For Euclidean vector spaces of dimension $3$ or less, we have a physical intuition for orientation which is connected to our sense of direction—direction of movement along a line, clockwise vs. counterclockwise rotations in the plane, the right-hand rule for Euclidean space. If we examine the effects of (matrices of) linear transformations on this, we will find that those with negative determinant reverse these directions and those with positive determinant leave them unchanged: multiplying by a negative number reverses motion along a path; reflections on the plane change clockwise rotations into counterclockwise ones, and so on. We classify linear transformations as *orientation-changing* or *orientation-preserving* accordingly.

Notice that there is no *intrinsic* property of these vector spaces qua vector spaces that allows us to say that a particular orientation is “positive,” “good” or whatever term we’d like to use. We make a choice based on external criteria. From the point of view of a pure vector space, this choice is entirely arbitrary. As someone else put it recently, aside from some harmless changes of sign here and there, everything works the same way regardless of this choice.

In higher-dimensional spaces, we run into a problem: most of us don’t have a geometric intuition to fall back on that will let us define “right-handed.” When considering more abstract vector spaces, there may not even be a geometrical model to fall back on. What would the right-hand rule even mean for the space of polynomials of degree less than three or the space of current flows in an electrical circuit with three resistors?

So, we basically *define* orientation via the determinants of change-of-basis matrices. Specifically, two bases $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr B'$ of $\mathbb R^n$ have the same orientation if the change-of-basis matrix that relates them has a positive determinant, and they have a different orientation if negative. Establishing the “good” orientation amounts to selecting one of these two equivalence classes. For more abstract real $n$-dimensional spaces, we observe that a choice of basis induces an isomorphism with $\mathbb R^n$, and that these isomorphisms then induce orientations in the abstract space.

Moving finally to the specific transformations you’re considering, the matrix that corresponds to swapping axes around in $\mathbb R^n$ is a *permutation matrix*, that is, the identity matrix with its columns permuted in the same way that the axes are to be rearranged. (Remember that the columns of the matrix are the images of the original axes.) It’s a basic property of determinants that swapping two columns of a matrix changes the sign of its determinant, so swapping a pair of axes is an orentation-changing transformation. To preserve the original orientation, we need to do something else that will also change the sign of the determinant. Flipping an axis multiplies the corresponding column by $-1$, so flipping an odd number of axes will do the trick, as will swapping other axes around so that you end up with an even permutation, or some other combination of these actions that results in a positive determinant. The bottom line is that, when you swap a pair of axes, some other axes have to come along for the ride as well if you want to keep the same orientation.

Comment: It still seems weird to me that the choice of which of the other axes that should be multiplied to $-1$ is arbitrary; what I think of when thinking of "right-handedness" has all to do with the *relative* position of the axes being a certain way. Say we're in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with basis $(x,y,z,w)$ and we swap $x,y.$ Then it doesn't seem that $(y,x,-z,w)$ and $(y,x,z,-w)$ would have the same relative positions of the axes.. I guess this is equivalent to saying that I find it weird if the three bases can be rotated onto each other, if that makes sense. Can this in fact be done?

Comment: @Lovsovs Things do get weird in $\mathbb R^4$ and higher, though I look at is as $\mathbb R^3$ being special in many ways. One thing that helps me understand what’s going on is that a rotation/reflection in a $2$-D subspace leaves an $(n-2)$-D subspace untouched. Once you move to $\mathbb R^4$, you’ve got room to do all kinds of interesting things independently of that rotation/reflection, unlike $\mathbb R^3$ where all you can do to get an orthogonal transformation is leave the normal to that plane fixed or flip it...

Comment: @Lovsovs It’s instructive to examine eigendecompositions of some of these transformations. For instance, by looking at the eigenspace of $-1$, the double-axis flip $x_1\leftrightarrows x_2$, $x_3\leftrightarrows x_4$ can be seen as a rotation in the $(1,-1,0,0)$-$(0,0,1,-1)$ plane; the transformation $x_1\leftrightarrows x_2$, $x_3\to-x_3$ is a rotation in the $(1,-1,0,0)$-$(0,0,1,0)$ plane, and so on.

Comment: @Lovsovs If you look at what these transformations do to the “handedness” of subsets of axes, things also get interesting. The double-swap flips the orientation of all four sets, while the swap+invert only flips three of them, yet both maintain the overall orientation of the vector space. In $\mathbb R^3$ there’s only one set of three axes, so there’s no choice about what to do there, but if you looks at what happens to the orientations of the coordinate planes, similar things occur.

Comment: Nice explanations! Not to get too philosophical, but I must say that I'm a bit awe-struck that mathematics allows us to say how things that lie completely beyond the scope of our (at least my) intuition behaves. Thanks again!